# Code isn't being run inside the $.get() success handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

These are my two jQuery functions

```
$(".enable_button").click(function(){
    var server_name = $(this).attr("title");
    $.get("ajax/server_ajax.php?action=enable&server_name=" + server_name), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});

$(".disable_button").click(function(){
    var server_name = $(this).attr("title");
    $.get("ajax/server_ajax.php?action=disable&server_name=" + server_name), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Pretty easy to see what they do, on a button click they enable or disable a server by passing an `action` parameter and `server_name` parameter to `ajax/server_ajax.php`. Everthing works, but for some reason the data being returned is never being alert'd. I can verify that it is correctly requesting that PHP file and the PHP file is returning data, as I can see it in the "Response" tab of Firebug.

I've also tried replacing the alert with `document.write(data)` and that doesn't work either.

Can anyone lend a hand? I'm clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the call to `get()` too early. The parenthesis after `+ server_name` shouldn't be there.

```
$.get("ajax/server_ajax.php?action=disable&server_name=" + server_name), function(data) {
                                                                    //^The ) shouldn't be here
    alert(data);
}
```

should be

```
$.get("ajax/server_ajax.php?action=disable&server_name=" + server_name, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}); //<-- close the call to get( over here, not after server_name.
```

---

Just an aside but with jQuery's ajax functions, you have the ability to pass an object for the data and jQuery will create the query string out of it, neatly escaping anything requires it. So you might do this which is equivalent to your original call for disable:

```
$.get("ajax/server_ajax.php", {"action" : "disable", "server_name" : server_name}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: This is why it's not advisable to code JavaScript in a pure text editor. No syntax error highlighting!

Comment: @Lotus I know I'd be in big trouble without it :)

Comment: ... that's embarrasing. It's been a long day :( Thanks!